# Uncaught TypeError: callback.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked accross the web but did not find an answer to this question, where does this error could came from ?

Im working on a really simple code where I just replace some text by an other.

### This is the HTML

```
<div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://voyagesarabais.com/1874431.jpg4fre);"</div>
<div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://voyagesarabais.com/159431.jpg4fre);"</div>
```

### This is the jQuery

```
$(document).each('.imgLittle',function(){
  newLink =  $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^(.*?\.jpg).*/, "$1");
  $(this).css('background-image',newLink)
})
```

But when I run it it come out with this output :

> Uncaught TypeError: callback.apply is not a function

You can have a look there : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n62djktu/5/).

Comment: `.each()` wants a function as its first parameter, you're passing a string. See Alexander's answer below for the correct usage.

Comment: `$(this).css('background-image').replace(/^(.*?\.jpg).*/, "$1");` is not going to do anything FYI. The image url is not going to be updated.

Comment: @epascarello indeed, just change the function thank you all !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) first argument should be function, like  this

```
$('.imgLittle').each(function() {
  // your code
})
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/n62djktu/6/)